# Mechanize to scrape using 2 searches?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am scraping a blog using Mechanize trying to get the results below. Mainly having trouble turning my thoughts into code logic. I assume I need to combine the search clauses and iterate through the html and prints out as it finds matches. New to using Rails and any advice will be helpful.

*Desired results:*

- first_title

  - first_image_url
  - second_image_url
- second_title

  - first_image_url
  - second_image_url

*Code:*

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

url = 'http://blog.something.com/'
mech = Mechanize.new
page = mech.get(url)

page.search('h2').each do |h2|
    puts h2.inner_text
end

imgs = page.search('img[src]').map{|src| src['src']}
puts imgs
```

*The code right of course produces:*

- first_title
- second_title
- third_title
- ...
- first_image_url
- second_image_url
- first_image_url
- ...

Answer (score 1):

assuming the images are descended from the h2 you could do:

```
page.search('h2').each do |h2|
  puts h2.inner_text
  h2.css('img').each do |img|
    puts img['src']
  end
end
```

Comment: What if 'img' is not descended from 'h2'? It is a different div. I tried this replacement for your `h2.css` `page.search('img').each do |img| puts img['src'] end`

Comment: In that case you would craft some xpath expression to get to the images. It depends on the markup.